# Android PubSubTutorial QR Code Scanner Bug

Tags: ros, rosjava, android, android-gingerbread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been running the PubSubTutorial app on my phone and it work perfectly fine except for when I try to scan a QR Code of the host IP Address. When I click the scan button in the app, it opens up the Bar Code scanner app on my phone, but when I scan the QR Code I get the following message:

"The application PubSubTutorial (process org.ros.android.app_chooser) has stopped unexpectedly."

After doing some digging around in the code behind the app, in particular how it handles the QR code scanning I came across this line(80) in org.android.ros.masterchooser:

Preconditions.checkstate(intent.getStringExtra("Scan_Result_Format").equals("Text_Type"));

After looking at what Preconditions.checkstate() and what intent.getStringExtra("Scan_Result_Format") does, I'm under the impression that the sole purpose of this line is to validate that the input is text.

If I comment out line 80 and scan in a QR code with the IP Address as text, the app works until I press "Ok" and then I get an "Invalid URI" message.

I changed my QR code to the IP Address as a URL, and the PubSubTutorial works correctly now.

Has anyone else had similar issues with scanning in a QR code? Is this line of code incorrectly implemented? Or is it a problem with my bar code scanner application not returning the expected type?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28869/android-pubsubtutorial-qr-code-scanner-bug/) by [itsalsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1869/itsalsman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elvish Champion](https://answers.ros.org/users/13736/elvish-champion/) on 2014-04-25**:
Hi, I am trying to make the same app but I am having many problems with the PubSub and the scanner. May I ask for your assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug is because intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT") is not "TEXT_TYPE".

I make a QR code on the following site, and the text extracted from intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT") is "QR_
CODE".

http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/

So, I think this is the easiest approach:

MasterChooser.java
line 84:
Preconditions.checkState(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT").equals("QR_CODE"));

But this line seems to be intented to check whether a type of the data is text or not.
So I guess there is a better approach.

---

Originally posted by [KazutoMurase](https://answers.ros.org/users/2505/kazutomurase/) with karma: 116 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please file an issue and attach the stack trace from logcat: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1